# Error reading from mapped type with generic key type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic class that takes in a union type and stores an element in a map based on the individual union type values. E.g.

```
type A { type: 'a'; }
type B { type: 'b'; }
type C = A | B;

type UnionType = { type: string; }
class MyClass<T extends UnionType> {
    private myMap: { [type in T['type']]?: Extract<T, { type: type }> } = {};    
}
```

This works great for setting. E.g. I can do something like this:

```
setValue(type: T['type'], value: Extract<T, { type: typeof type }>) {
    this.myMap[type] = value;
}
```

However, where I run in to problems is trying to read from the map. E.g.

```
getValue(value: T): T | undefined {
    return this.myMap[value.type]; // <- error 
}
```

The exact error is: `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type { [type in T['type']]?: Extract<T, { type: type }> }`.

This error *kind of* makes sense given the type definitions, but I'm unsure of a way to narrow down the possible values of `value.type` sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of stupid... TypeScript accepts this and doesn't complain:

```
getValue(value: T): T | undefined {
    const type: T['type'] = value.type;
    return this.myMap[type];
}
```